# Table and specific SQLQuery.sql to C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm importing the table 'tblTable' to Datagridview in C# with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        //
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTable";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sa.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();

    }
```

I have written a specific SQLQuery, 'SQLQuery1.sql' that does some groupings from the table 'tblTable' that I'm already importing. What would be the best way to import only the SQLQuyery1.sql in to C#, without importing all the table?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to paste the other SQL in the code in place of `"SELECT * FROM tblTable"` ?

Comment: Sorted with stored procedures in the @JamesCurran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be best to make your query into a Stored Procedure, and call instead:

```
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine with Stored procedures.